# Youtube-like IDs that change accordingly with an indentifier

Tags: php, mysql, random, youtube

I was thinking about how to make a `small function` that generates a `YouTube`-like `ID` and does not cause collisions. The charset should be `A-Za-z0-9-_` and lets say I want it to be `10 characters` long which would equal `64 ^ 10 / Quadrillion` - `1153 Quadrillion` possibilities.

It's rather important to be `small` due to the fact that it's one of the major functionality of the website and should be clear enough to be modified easily. Within seconds in case an emergency occurs.

It doesn't have to be `secure` in the sense that we don't really mind whether it's easily to convert back to an `ID` as an outsider. It should however not be a pattern such as:

`aaaaaaaaaa`
`aaaaaaaaab`
`aaaaaaaaac`

I'm aware that you could theoretically make a `charset` and loop through it randomly until you have `10` random characters but this could collide ( I realize this chance is slim and you could perform a query to see whether the `key` has been generated before but I would like to keep dependencies minimal and it not relying on `SQL` ).

I can also imagine making a `charset` of `100 characters` as in `0-99` and then prepend and/or append `random` characters if the `length of 10` condition is not met. Eg:

- **IMPORTANT**: the scenario sketched below assumes `A` is the first character in the set and `_` is the last one.

### `id: 0 = A+9 random characters`

### `id: 1 = B+9 random characters`

### `id: 99 = _+9 random characters`

### `id: 990 = _A+8 random characters`

### `id: 99999999999999999999 = __________`

I would think that would prevent `collisions` but I don't have a `charset` of `100` but `64`.

Hope someone can toss some ideas.

- **UPDATE1**: The above sketch *could* actually collide in the following (and more) circumstance(s):
- If the `ID` is `99` it doesn't mean that the next character can't be `A` by `chance` although very unlikely; it *could* therefore `collide` with `990` :-(
- **UPDATE2**: I don't think it would still collide if we use a `static component` after the `ID` and before the `random component` that is not part of the `charset`.
- Updated Sketch (the static component will be $):

### `id: 0 = A$+8 random characters`

### `id: 1 = B$+8 random characters`

### `id: 99 = _$+8 random characters`

### `id: 990 = _A$+7 random characters`

### `id: 999999999999999999 = _________$`

Comment: Is something like base64/32 encoded UUIDs a possibility?

Comment: @The6P4C Well, that would be practically unique and not guaranteed afaik

Answer (score 0):

as in your other question here [Encode/Decode ID Reversal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002969/encode-decode-id-reversal-issue) all you want is to transform your ID which is in base 10 to a different base than 10 ...

you could simply base64 encode it and be done ...

if you want it to look like random, transform the number before ... for example, simply xor it with a static 60 bit value ...